# Reading in a text file using C# and accessing parts of the input

Tags: c#

I have the following code...

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\maze2.txt");
int row = lines[0][0];
int col = lines[0][1];
```

The first line in the text file is a number, a space and then another number. All the subsequent lines are text. These numbers represent the the number of rows and columns in the text file. However, when I try assigning the row and column values to my variables, it gives the ASCII char value and I want the number.

Comment: please format the code

Comment: You need to parse a string using `int.Parse()` or `int.TryParse()`

Comment: `lines[0][0]` is the first char (digit) from first line.

Comment: Consider a CSV reader (where the space is the separator) like this one: https://github.com/tspence/csharp-csv-reader

Comment: Yes, using a comma would be better than a space, but either way, I'd suggest using String.Split(' ') or String.Split(',') to get your row and column values separated.

Answer (score 3):

Because when you index a string as an array, you get a character.  And the numeric representation of a character is its ASCII byte.

> The first line in the text file is a number, a space and then another number.

So then `lines[0]` is a string with two numbers separated by a single space?  If so then you can split it by that space.  For example:

```
var numbers = lines[0].Split(' ');
```

This would make `numbers` an array of two strings, the numeric values you want.  You can then parse those values.  For example:

```
var rowCount = int.Parse(numbers[0]);
var columnCount = int.Parse(numbers[1]);
```

Note that there's no error checking/handling in any of this.  You can write more defensive code by checking array lengths before indexing them, making use of `TryParse` instead of `Parse`, etc.